# Dynamic React Router and component not possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a dynamic router with React. The idea is that the Routes are created from the data (object) received from the backend:

Menu Object:

```
items: [
    {
      name: "dashboard",
      icon: "dashboard",
      placeholder: "Dashboard",
      path: "/",
      page: "Dashboard",
      exact: true,
    },
    {
      name: "suppliers",
      icon: "suppliers",
      placeholder: "Suppliers",
      path: "/suppliers",
      page: "Suppliers",
      exact: true,
    }
]
```

The routes hook :

```
export const RouteHook = () => {
  // Dispatch to fetch the menu object from the backend
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(setMenu());

  // Select the menu and items from Redux
  const { items } = useSelector(getMainMenu);

  // useState to set the routes inside
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);

  
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Loop trough the menu Items
    for (const item of items) {
      const { page, path, name, exact } = item;

      // Import dynamically the route components
      import(`../pages/${name}/${page}`).then((result) => {
        // Set the routes inside the useState
        setMenuItems(
          <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={result[page]} />
        );
      });
    }
     // Check if pathname has changed to update the useEffect
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <Switch>
      {/* Set the routes inside the switch */}
      {menuItems}
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Now here's the problem. Not all the components load. Usually the last component loads and when clicking on a diffrent route the component won't change. Except if you got to the page and refresh (F5).

What am I missing here? Is it possible to create full dynamic routes & components in react?

Comment: Why does your `useEffect` depend on `pathname`?  The routes are the same no matter what the current path is.  The matching of the current path to the correct `Route` is handled by react-router-dom.

Comment: I see that I made a mistake there. I tought that I needed to check if the path has changed, if so re-run the useEffect. But from the answers below I see that this was absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seth has some great suggestions, but here's how you can clean this up while still using dynamic imports.

Hopefully you can see that you are calling `setMenuItems` with a single `Route` component instead of all of them.  Each time that you `setMenuItems` you are overriding the previous result and that's why only the last `Route` actually works -- it's the only one that exists!

Your `useEffect` depends on the `pathname` which seems like you are trying to do the routing yourself.  Since you are using `react-router-dom` you would include **all** of the `Route` components in your `Switch` and let the router handle the routing.

So you don't actually need any state here.

You can use the [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactlazy) component import helper inside of the `Route`.  You need a [`Suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) provider around the whole block in order to use lazy imports.

I don't like that you use two variables in the path for a component `../pages/${name}/${page}`.  Why not export the component from the `./index.js` of the folder?

```
export const Routes = () => {
  // Dispatch to fetch the menu object from the backend
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(setMenu());

  // Select the menu and items from Redux
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.routes.items);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={() => <div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        {items.map(({ exact, path, name }) => (
          <Route
            key={name}
            exact={exact}
            path={path}
            component={React.lazy(() => import(`../pages/${name}`))}
          />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

It works!

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-dynamic-routing-rboic?file=/src/components/Routes.tsx)

Comment: Your code didnt work for me, After some investigation I found out that one of the mistakes was in the way that I exported the components. I only had the export const function. And no export default function. React lazy does not (I think?) import and deconstruct the component. It has to be and default export. Now your code works! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure 100% what's going on here, but here's a problem I see:

```js
const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);
```

You're saying that `menuItems` is an array of something.  But then:

```js
import(`../pages/${name}/${page}`).then((result) => {
  // Set the routes inside the useState
  setMenuItems(
    <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={result[page]} />
  );
});
```

On every iteration you are setting the menu items to be a singular `Route` component.  Probably what you're thinking youre doing is

```js
const routes = items.map(item => {

  const { page, path, name, exact } = item;

  return import(`../pages/${name}/${page}`).then((result) => {
    <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={result[page]} />
  });

})

setMenuItems(routes)
```

But this makes no sense, because your `map` statement is returning a `Promise.then` function.  I'm not entirely sure why you're dynamically importing the components here.  You're better off doing a simple route mapping:

```js
const routes = items.map(item => {

  const { page, path, name, exact } = item;

  return <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={components[page]} />

})

setMenuItems(routes)
```

Where `components` is an object whose keys are the values of `page` and whose values are actual components, i.e.:

```
const components = {
  Suppliers: RenderSuppliers,
  Dashboard: RenderDashboard
}
```

If you want these components lazy-loaded, use react suspense:

```
const Suppliers = React.lazy(() => import("./Suppliers"))
const Dashboard = React.lazy(() => import("./Dashboard"))

const components = {
  Suppliers,
  Dashboard,
}


const routes = items.map(item => {
  const { page, path, name, exact } = item;

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<SomeFallbackComponent />}>
      <Route
        exact={exact}
        path={path}
        component={components[page]}
      />
    </Suspense>
  )

})

setMenuItems(routes)
```

This is just a quick review of what may be going wrong with your code, without a reproducible example, its hard to say exactly.

Comment: Oke, I think that this will solve my problem. I want to build dynamic router with dynamic components. I will try to setup a codesandbox (I'm a junior so bare with me)

Comment: I agree with the vast majority of what you're said here, but I would make a map of the components themselves without instantiating them.  `Suppliers: Suppliers` instead of `Suppliers: <Suppliers>`.  Is it cool if I edit your answer?  Because the `children` prop actually behaves differently than the `component` prop and you don't want to use `children`.

Comment: Yes, go ahead!  Let's collab